# sed command to rplace a line with multiple lines without changing the format of the file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the below xml file

```
cat example.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Text>
                <Checking state="BOOT" />
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user1" num="1" Mode="NA" Type="OPEN" txt="NA-TO" TextType="guest" who="BANANNA"/>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user2" num="2" Mode="YA" Type="DYNAMIC-WEP" txt="NA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA" />
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user3" num="3" Mode="YA" Type="DYNAMIC-WEP" txt="NA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA"/>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user4" num="4" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="CA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA">
                        <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
                </function>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user5" num="5" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="CA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA">
                        <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
                </function>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user6" num="7" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA">
                        <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
                </function>
        </Text>
</TestConfig>
```

In this file, I would like to change the line 5 from

```
        <function name="configure" type="test" username="user1" num="1" Mode="NA" Type="OPEN" txt="NA-TO" TextType="guest" who="BANANNA"/>
```

to

```
        <function name="configure" type="test" username="user1" num="1" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="NA-TO" TextType="guest" who="BANANNA">
                <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
        </function>
```

Comment: I missed it or you forgot to paste the file ? If I understand your needs you want to change line 5 whatever it contains ? sed -i '5s/pattern/newpattern/' file.xml would be ok then .

Comment: How are you selecting line 5? Is it always line 5? or are you looking for a pattern on line 5? Do you want to change all lines with `<function .* />`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, in this example it is line 5.

Comment: Can you use an XML editor, which is tailor-made to edit XML, rather than some shell pipeline, which are [notoriously poor at parsing XML/XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Comment: Your question title mentions “without changing the format of the file”, but your question body doesn’t elaborate. Is your concern that the new lines should dynamically match the indentation of the existing line(s)? If so, see [How can I tag text based on its indentation?](https://superuser.com/q/1204467/354511)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the new file newcontent.txt. putting the content which you want to replace with.

---

```
Cat new content.txt
<function name="configure" type="test" username="user1" num="1" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="NA-TO" TextType="guest" who="BANANNA">
                <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
        </function>
```

---

Use below command to get the content replaced as per your requirement

---

```
sed '5r newcontent.txt' example2.txt  | sed ‘5d'.
```

---

example2.txt==> original input file

newcontent.txt==> Consists of content which need to replaced

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Text>
                <Checking state="BOOT" />
<function name="configure" type="test" username="user1" num="1" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="NA-TO" TextType="guest" who="BANANNA">
                <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
        </function>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user2" num="2" Mode="YA" Type="DYNAMIC-WEP" txt="NA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA" />
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user3" num="3" Mode="YA" Type="DYNAMIC-WEP" txt="NA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA"/>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user4" num="4" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="CA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA">
                        <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
                </function>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user5" num="5" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" txt="CA-TO" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA">
                        <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
                </function>
                <function name="configure" type="test" username="user6" num="7" Mode="YA" Type="WPA2-PSK" TextType="employee" who="BANANNA">
                        <parameters name="_key" value="password" isit="true" />
                </function>
        </Text>
</TestConfig>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR!=5{print} NR==5{ print "        <function name=\"configure\" type=\"test\" username=\"user1\" num=\"1\" Mode=\"YA\" Type=\"WPA2-PSK\" txt=\"NA-TO\" TextType=\"guest\" who=\"BANANNA\">"; print "                <parameters name=\"_key\" value=\"password\" isit=\"true\" />"; print ""}' /path/to/some.xml
```

Comment: Can we do this generic, irrespective of line number as 5. .

Comment: Based on what set of criteria?

Comment: let the same line be on line 6 or 7 not specifically at line 5, just a random line number, but the content will be same and only one entry per file

Comment: In the OP, you ask specifically for how to change the fifth line with no reference to its content or the other similar lines in your example input file.  Ask for what you want rather than telling people who give you what you ask for that they did not give you what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions to parse or edit XML.  It doesn't work reliably, and can not be made to work reliably - even if you do hack up something that "works", even tiny changes or unexpected variations in the input XML file can break any regex-only script.

Instead, use either:

- a programming language such as `perl` or `python` (or many others) that have XML parsing libraries.
- a command-line tool like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), which is available pre-packaged for most linux distributions and other unix-like systems.

If you really must use `sed` or `awk`, then use [xml2](https://github.com/clone/xml2) to convert the XML data into a line-oriented format suitable for processing with such tools, and then `2xml` to convert it back to properly formatted XML afterwards.  e.g.

```
xml2 < yourxmlfile | your sed/awk script here | 2xml > newxmlfile
```